# How to add multiple attribute in single element using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a piece of XML code which starts element like below.

```
<fundingAgreement messageTimeStamp="2015-03-03T12:19:51.679+00:00" messageType="XYZ" schemeAgency="TESTCOMPANY" xmlns="http://www.test.co.uk/xyz/xmlModel/funding">
```

How is it I can design this in XSD, if I want to generate XML with the above format?

Currently, it comes like below.

```
<fundingAgreement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using below definition

```
  <xs:element name="fundingAgreement" type="fundingAgreementType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="fundingAgreementType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:dateTime" name="messageTimeStamp"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="messageType"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="schemeAgency"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```